# Algorithm - Balancing a disconnected bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, bipartite

I have a bipartite graph `G`. I would like to find a fast algorithm (asymptotically) to find an assignment of all the vertices of `G` into two sets `X` and `Y` such that the complete bipartite graph formed by the sets `X` and `Y` has as many edges as possible.

**Slightly longer explanation**:

`G` is bipartite and consists of a set connected components (each of which are bipartite, obviously). We want to decide on a positioning (for lack of a better word) of each component into `X` and `Y`. After deciding upon all the positionings, we complete the bipartite graph (i.e. we connect every vertex of `X` to every vertex of `Y`). We then count out how many edges are there totally (including original edges) and we want to maximize this count. Simple math shows that the number of edges would be `|X|*|Y|`.

**My thought process for a solution:**

As the number of components increase, the number of choices for `G` increases exponentially. However, if we take number of connected components of `G` to be equal to number of nodes in `G`, then the solution is simple - split so that number of nodes in `X` and `Y` are equal (or almost equal in case of odd number of nodes in `G`). This makes me want to generalize that the problem is the same thing as trying to minimize the difference in cardinalities of `X` and `Y` (which can be solved as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743141/split-vertices-of-disconnected-bipartite-graph-equally)). However, I have been unsuccessful in proving so.

Comment: I am not following one thing, `we complete the bipartite graph (i.e. we connect every vertex of X to every vertex of Y). We then count out how many edges are there totally (including original edges) and we want to maximize this count` But, as you said, the number of these edges is already known and is |X|*|Y|. How do you count the edges to make it vary?

Comment: @amit: The counting always leads to `|X|*|Y|`, however, `|X|` and `|Y|` vary based upon how we decide to "position" each component of the (disconnected) `G`.

Comment: Still not following. What exactly you need to maximize? Sum of all such |X|*|Y|? Do the edges come into play anywhere (except determining the "sides" of the bipartite graph)?

Comment: I want to get the maximum |X|*|Y| among all the possibilities of |X|*|Y|. The original edges of `G` decide which components are there, but after that, the edges don't matter, only the assignment of each vertex into `X` or `Y` matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's decompose the problem.

1. Your graph is actually a set of connected components, each connected
   component is `(U_i,V_i,E_i)`.
2. To maximize the number of edges, you need to maximize the value of
   `|X|*|Y|`
3. To get the maximal value of `|X|*|Y|`, you obviously need to use all
   vertices (otherwise, by adding another vertex, you get a bigger value).
4. Your freedom of choice is actually to choose for each component `i` - if you should add `U_i` to `X`, and `V_i` to `Y` - or vise versa.

So, what you are actually trying to do is:

```
maximize:
sum { x_i * |V_i| : for each component i} * sum { y_i * |U_i| : for each component i}
subject to constraints:
x_i, y_i in {0,1} for all i
x_i + y_i = 1     for all i
```

The value we want to maximize behaves similar to the function `f(x) = x(k-x)`, because if we increase `|X|`, it comes at the expanse of decreasing `|Y|`, and by the same amount. This function has a single maximum:

```
f(x) = xk - x^2
f'(x) = k - 2x = 0  ---> x = k/2
```

Meaning, we should distribute the nodes such that the cardinality (size) of `X` and `Y` are closest as possible to each other (and use all the vertices).

This can be reduced to [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem):

```
Given U_1,V_1,U_2,V_2,...,U_k,V_k
Create an instance of partition problem:
abs(|U_1| - |V_1|), abs(|U_2| - |V_2|), ... , abs(|U_k| - |V_k|)
```

Now, the optimal solution found to partition problem can be translated directly to which of U_i,V_i to include in which set, and will make sure the difference in sizes is kept to minimum.